# How do I create a model that "belongsTo" a "hasMany through" join model?

Tags: php, cakephp, relationship, cakephp-2.4

I'm gonna use the `CourseMembership` example from the CakePHP manual to illustrate my question. So there are the following tables:

`CREATE TABLE course (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
course_name VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE student (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
student_name VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE course_membership (
course_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES(course.id),
student_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES(student.id),
attended_lectures TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (course_id, student_id)
);`

My models look like this:

```
class Course extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('CourseMembership');
}
class Student extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('CourseMembership');
}
class CourseMembership extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Course', 'Student');
}
```

What is the best way to add a `CourseMembershipProperty` model/table to this setup? I'm curious about both the schema and the relationship configuration in the model class.

The relationships should be:

- `CourseMembershipProperty` belongsTo `CourseMembership`
- `CourseMembership` hasMany `CourseMembershipProperty`.

For simplicity's sake, the `CourseMembershipProperty` model's table can have two `VARCHAR` fields, `name` and `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

Your table names should be pluralized:

`course` should be `courses`

`student` should be `students`

`course_membership` should be `course_memberships`

Note this section from the CakePHP cookbook:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

> "CakePHP does not support composite primary keys."

The `course_memberships` table should have a primary key of `id` that auto increments and the composite primary keys of course_id and student_id should be removed and be utilized as foreign keys. Without first correcting this problem, the CourseMembership model will misbehave.

After that, the `CourseMembershipProperty` model should link to the `CourseMembership` model by using a foreign key of `course_membership_id`. This should work by simply defining the Models as you have in your example since we will be following the CakePHP naming conventions at this point.